# Jumbotron image not showing up

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add an image to my jumbtron but nothing but the default background is showing up when I load the page?

HTML

```
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Welcome to y</h1>
          <p>We  blablabla</p>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron .jumbotron-fluid{
      background-image: url(‘../img/bghead.jpg’);
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.jumbotron h1{
  font-family: 'Opens Sans' sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

Comment: `url(‘../img/bghead.jpg’)` is incorrect. It's supposed to be `url('../img/bghead.jpg')` I dont know where you got that symbol from, but look at `'Opens Sans'` see how it is `'` not `’` (Honestly couldn't find it on my keyboard had to copy and paste that symbol.)

Comment: Thanks that sorted the problem! The symbol is on my keyboard in the UK

Comment: Awesome! Ahh makes sense why I couldn't find it, haha.